# Should C++ allocator::allocate throw or return nullptr when allocation fails?

Tags: c++, std, allocator

The [Allocator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) and [std::allocator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/allocate) do not say what `allocate` will do when allocation fail -- will it returns nullptr or throw?

When I'm writing a container using standard allocator API, should I

1. Check the return value and catch the exception in the `noexcept` version member function(E.g. `push_back`, `resize`...);
2. Check the return value and throw if fail in the exception-throwing one

so that no matter it throws or not, I will get the correct behavior.

Comment: Allocators usually throw `std::bad_alloc` to report that allocating has failed. Also note that the `push_back` and `resize` functions of standard containers are usually NOT `noexcept`.

Comment: Looking at [libc++ sources](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/vector#L2514), there is no check for a `nullptr` return value...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Draft n4659 for C++ standard says at 23.10.9 The default allocator [default.allocator] (emphasize mine):

> 23.10.9.1 allocator members [allocator.members]
>   
> ...
>
> ```
> T* allocate(size_t n);
> ```
>
> 2 Returns: A pointer to the initial element of an array of storage of size n * sizeof(T), aligned
>   appropriately for objects of type T.
>   3 Remarks: the storage is obtained by calling ::operator new (21.6.2), but it is unspecified when or
>   how often this function is called.
>   4 **Throws: bad_alloc if the storage cannot be obtained.**

It makes it clear that the standard allocator will raise a `bad_alloc` exception if it cannot allocate storage.

---

Above is for the standard allocator. The requirement for any allocator are described in 20.5.3.5 Allocator requirements [allocator.requirements] and table 31 — Allocator requirements contains:

> a.allocate(n) [Return type:] X::pointer [Assertion/note/
>   pre-/post-condition]Memory is allocated for n
>   objects of type T but objects are
>   not constructed. allocate may
>   throw an appropriate
>   exception

My understanding is that `allocate` can return only when memory has been allocated. So the allocator should throw an appropriate exception (not necessarily `bad_alloc` even if it would be quite appropriate) if memory could not be allocated.

Comment: But there's really no explicit saying on whether it should throw or not.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu: What is written is that it shall return a pointer to allocated memory and that it may throw. There is no provision for returning a null pointer when it cannot allocate. You are right it is not explicit but many things are not more explicit than that in C++ standard...